# Angular cannot import module after upgrading to version 8

Tags: angular8

I am updating angular version 7 to 8. using ng update @angular/cli @angular/core command but angular is not automatically changing route syntax and imports

Comment: Why would the route syntax and imports change?

Comment: Please check below url "After the Update" section.
https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

Comment: You need to update manually.

Comment: Okay. and when i am using "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core" command i am getting error "Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency"

Comment: Could you update the dependency and see the result?

Comment: After updating getting below mentioned error
"Package "ng-snotify" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.0.0")"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194446/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-bordia-and-damien-asseya).